# Ficus elastica — Will its leaves uncurl?

Tags: watering, leaves, figs, ficus

I started getting a bit of leaf curl on a rubber fig we bought for our studio a few weeks ago. The soil felt a little damp, so I've slowed down on the watering, but gave the leaves a mist once this week because I hadn't before.

My question is, will the leaves uncurl once they're happy again, or do they stay like this?

[image: Ficus with leaves curled]

Comment: How long have you had it? I might suggest giving it less water when you water (my rubber plant seems to curl less when I do that; I used to think it needed like a gallon, since it's a very large plant, but no; it's happier with less), and increasing light. I can't say if the leaves will recover, though.

Comment: This question has a bounty. Rowen, have you tried what user22542 suggested?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the plant is suffering from low, insufficient light conditions. For some reason, people like to place plants where they cannot truly grow or thrive. The plant seems reasonably healthy. The soil is probably adequate. The plant seems neither overwatered or dehydrated. Low light often affects the strength and formation of new growth.

The leaves that have already "curled" will probably not correct themselves, but try placing the plant in brighter more natural light conditions and see if any new growth in the future comes in better formed.